# How can I print number of occurences of an array from an array list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an arraylist that contains some arrays, I want to print out the arraylist, if an array in the arraylist is repeated then print it only one time with a number of occurences next to it. (Assumes all arrays are sorted from smallest to biggest)

Here is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] a2 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] a3 = {1,2,3,4,5};

        int[] a4 = {2,5,7,8,9};
        int[] a5 = {2,5,7,8,9};

        int[] a6 = {3,4,6,8,9};

        ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(a1);
        list.add(a2);
        list.add(a3);
        list.add(a4);
        list.add(a5);
        list.add(a6);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

Here is the output that I want:

```
1,2,3,4,5 (3)
2,5,7,8,9 (2)
3,4,6,8,9
```

(If it unique then don't need occurences number)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you used `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]` it would be trivial. Is that possible?

Comment: @Bohemian I thought of using List<String> and use Collections.frequency() to get the occurrences, however I'm still struggling to print out only one time with the total occurrences

Comment: Is that a “yes” then? That `List<Integer>` can be used instead of `int[]`?

Comment: Oh yes for sure, as long as I can get the result. However how it will work with List<Integer>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`, because List’s `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method can be used to good effect.

Assuming:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(List.of(1,2,3,4,5));
// etc
```

Then it’s a one-liner:

```
list.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```